# jQuery - Get part of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JS/jQuery, I need to strip a YouTube embed code to reveal just the SRC value. How is this possible?

The embed code, for example:

```
string = "<iframe width="630" height="354" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NYjPglsyYZA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
```

I am looking to grab everything between `src="` and `"`. I'm thinking maybe a regular expression will do it but not overly sure...

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: So you have this HTML as a string? Or what?

Comment: @FelixKling: Doh! Forgot the string part! Edited.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid added from a string version to my answer

Comment: @FelixKling: I did actually write "string" in the original question title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try :

```
var str='<iframe width="630" height="354" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NYjPglsyYZA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; 
var src = $(str).attr("src");
```

Comment: Really sorry mate. I forgot a key part of my question. The embed code is actually a string, not an element.

Comment: Nice one! That's really nifty and simple, thanks a million :)

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery:

```
$('iframe:first').attr('src');
```

In plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src;
```

---

**UPDATE**

Starting with a string, using jQuery:

```
string = '<iframe width="630" height="354" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NYjPglsyYZA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
var src = $(string).attr('src');
```

And without jQuery:

```
string = '<iframe width="630" height="354" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NYjPglsyYZA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = string;
var src = div.firstChild.src;

alert(src);
```

​

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Try this

```
var str='<iframe width="630" height="354" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NYjPglsyYZA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; 
var n=str.match(/src="(.*)"/);
var result = n.substring(5,n.length()-1);
```